# what is solution for "datetime.date(2014, 3, 14) is not JSON serializable"?

Tags: date, datetime, python-3.3

i am trying to append date in the list,the code for this is below.

```
  t=(['%s (%s)'% (w[0], w[1]) for w in top_10_words_sans_stop_words])
#print t

    today = datetime.date.today()
    times_list.append({'title':t,'date':today})
    print(times_list)
out_file = os.path.join('database', 'Tuesday','stopwords','timesofindia.json')
f = open(out_file, 'w')
f.write(json.dumps(times_list, indent=1))
f.close()

print('Wrote output file to %s' % (f.name, ))
```

but it gives error like that
so what is the proper solution for this error?

```
datetime.date(2014, 3, 14) is not JSON serializable
```